# How can I get a button to determine which viewcontroller to go to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to use Xcode to take the value of a usertype input and do one of three things: if the usertype is invalid it will stay on the current view controller and tell the user the credentials are invalid, if it is valid and "admin" it will go to the user settings, and if it is "user" or null it will go to the order list.

I already have the if statements built, just not sure how to specify what view controller to go to.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Are you using Storyboard or IB. Do you have a navigation controller to push new view controller ? Do you want to just present new view controller ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your question, but can't you simply allocate the view like this:

```
if(!error) {
   ViewController *viewcont = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:viewcont animated:NO completion:nil];
} else {
 ViewController2 *viewcont2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:viewcont2 animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using navigation controller

```
if(!error) {
   ViewController *view1 = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view1 animated:YES];
} else {
 ViewController2 *view2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
}
```

Otherwise use this

```
if(!error) {
   ViewController *view1 = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:view1 animated:NO completion:nil];
} else {
 ViewController2 *view2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:view2 animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Remember: this solution will not work if your views are not `xnib` files, I mean if you are using storyboard